# How can I use ColorThief to obtain the dominant color of multiple images?

Tags: python, image, colors

I have a folder on my desktop of about 1,000 images and I'm hoping to use **ColorThief** in **Python** to obtain the dominant color (in RGB format) for each one. I found the following code, but this obviously only works for one image at a time.

color_thief = ColorThief('/path/to/file')

dominant_color = color_thief.get_color(quality=1)
print(dominant_color)

Is there a way to do the whole batch of images at once? I am hoping to get the file name as one column and the RGB value as the other.

Only able to use one image at a time with current code.

Comment: That package does not give you enough information for a true answer itself. You might stitch the images together then use it or use some combination of the individual palettes to guess at a color.

Comment: @JonSG Sorry, not sure I understand what you mean it won't give enough information for a true answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `os.listdir()` to get all the images in your directory:

```py
import os
from colorthief import ColorThief

image_path = '/path/to'

images = [image for image in os.listdir(image_path)]  # assuming only images are in the path

dominant_colors = {}

for image in images:
    color_thief = ColorThief(os.path.join(image_path, image))

    dominant_colors.update({(image, color_thief.get_color(quality=1))})

for image, dominant_color in dominant_colors.items():
    print(image, dominant_color)
```

I saved the dominant colors in a dictionary so when printing you get the image name with the corresponding dominant color.

Comment: It looks like your code sample is not executable. There is no closing to `{` in `dominant_colors.update{(image, color_thief.get_color(quality=1)`? The import to `ColorThief` is missing...

Comment: Whoops, should be fixed now.

Comment: `glob` might be easier to use than `listdir` especially if you need to filter by extension.

Comment: Syntax still isn't quite right.

Comment: Thank you @BRemmelzwaal !!! I just had to change "images_path" to "image_path" in row 11, but after that, it worked. Exactly what I needed!

Comment: @JC91 It seems my typos are endless, but glad it works :)

Comment: I already have an image open in memory (PIL.Image type). Does color_thief accept it? Or it has to be a file?

Comment: @TinaJ As far as I can tell from the Color Thief and PIL documentation, Color Thief _should_ support PIL images. You can always try.